# VBA for truncating data in an MS Excel cell

Tags: excel, vba, cell, truncate

I have an Excel spreadsheet with some 4000 instances of data entered in a cell as (for example) =234+3455+456+876. [The data are stock market related.]  It turns out I only need the first two data elements.  Each datum can be anywhere from 1 to 4 or 5 characters long.

I'm VBA illiterate, but was wondering if someone could point me toward a macro or global command that would truncate the string after the last digit of the first two data elements. So, the above string would end up as =234+3455.  Maybe an "if, then" function of some sort?  How would I apply same to the entire spreadsheet?

At this point, I could probably have just manually deleted the 4000 cells, but now it has become a challenge!!  I also realize I really need to learn VBA!

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How about a formula? No need for VBA

=LEFT(A1;FIND("+";A1;FIND("+";A1)+1)-1)

Assuming data you want to truncate is in cell A1

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I will work with your solution to familiarize myself with the syntax. I actually solved the problem by using the "text to columns" function and directing the function to consider "+" signs as delimiters.  This broke the four number entries into four columns and then I simply deleted the two unwanted columns and summed the two columns I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this problem is to use the "Text to Columns" function and direct the function to consider "+" signs as delimiters.  This broke the four numbers in the cell into four numbers, each in its own cell across four columns.  I could then delete the last two columns and then sum the first two columns.